# PHP CURL post request and Error 417

Tags: php, curl

```
function query($url, $pfields = 0, $cookie = 0)
{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    if (!empty($pfields))
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pfields);
    }            
    if (!empty($cookie))
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);            
    }            
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip');
    if (!$login)
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    }
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    return $content;
}

$cookie = 'sessionID=3864cab58412ec567b634db3c317898;OAGEO=RU%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C;';
$p = '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++';
$post = 'clientid=23&campaignid=52&bannerid=111&appendsave=1&appendtype=0&append=' . urlencode($p) . '&submitbutton=';

echo query('http://example.com/in.php', $post, $cookie);
```

This code is returned 417 error(
BUT $p is not usage urlencode but IS OK but +(plus) change for " "(space)

Sooooorry for my very bad english

Comment: In theory your code could/should work, and a 417 is reserved for a wrong `Expect` header, which you aren't sending. The server itself might be misbehaving, you could try to get extra data why it's failing by using  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);`

Comment: Curl automatically adds it for "large" posts. Certain servers, like lighttpd, don't support it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
```

Comment: +1. Any chance at an explanation as to why this works?

Comment: @Nate, Curl automatically is adding the Expect/100-Continue header for "large" posts. In short, this allows for a client to ask the server for permission before it posts a large block of data. (i.e., Why post data if the server is going to reject your request?) Some servers, notably lighttpd, don't support this and instead of silently failing, they produce an error. The above code simply clears out that header and sends a regular request.